# wmic change default output format(get only process executable path)

Tags: windows, process, wmi

Using wmic to get information about process.

```
wmic process where processid="<PID>"
```

gives many details (Caption, creationtime, arguments, ExecutablePath etc) .  Right now I am processing the output to get name and process-executable-path. Is there any formatting option to get same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off using Powershell's `gwmi` to more efficiently extract and format the data you want.